# How to sort array of value by alpha bet in php using asort() function()

Tags: php

I'm using code:

```
<?php
$fruits = array("1" => "1.jpeg", "2" => "10.jpg", "3" => "11.jpeg", "4" => "12.jpeg", "4" => "2.jpeg");
asort($fruits);
foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
    echo "$val\n";
}
```

> input:

```
1.jpeg 
10.jpg 
11.jpeg 
2.jpeg
```

> I want input as

```
1.jpeg 
2.jpeg
10.jpg 
11.jpeg
```

> ```
> help with me
> ```

Comment: You can use the sort function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php

Comment: What you want isn't really sorted by alphabet though, it's sorted by numeric values in the beginning of a string. Sorting alphabeticly will sort by first character first, like asort does now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also look at: [natsort](http://php.net/manual/function.natsort.php). It does exactly what you want. It even features almost the same sample data.

```
$fruits = array("1" => "1.jpeg", "2" => "10.jpg", "3" => "11.jpeg", "4" => "12.jpeg", "4" => "2.jpeg");
natsort($fruits);
foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
    echo "$val\n";
}
```

Output:

```
1.jpeg
2.jpeg
10.jpg
11.jpeg
```

Comment: and where is `"12.jpeg"` ? :)

Comment: @k102 More of an array-definition problem than a sorting problem, is it not? ;)

Comment: The OP didn't put it in his output.

Answer (score 2):

use `asort($fruits,SORT_NUMERIC);`

Comment: and you've got an error in your code: `"4" => "12.jpeg", "4" => "2.jpeg"` double `4` key

Answer (score 0):

```
  function subval_sort($a,$subkey) {
foreach($a as $k=>$v) {
    $b[$k] = strtolower($v[$subkey]);
}
asort($b);
foreach($b as $key=>$val) {
    $c[] = $a[$key];
}
return $c;
```

}

or do like this:

```
  ksort($arrTags);
  arsort($arrTags);
```

Try this